# How to prevent race condition in Django on INSERT with limiting SUM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Consider two models:

- **Project**:

  - id: An `AutoField` primary key
  - budget: A `PositiveIntegerField`
  - some unrelated fields
- **Expense**

  - id: An `AutoField` primary key
  - amount: A `PositiveIntegerField`
  - project: A `ForeignKey` to `Project`
  - some unrelated fields

For each project, I wish to ensure that the sum of their expenses is less than or equal to the budget at all times.

In SQL terms: `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expense WHERE project_id = ?;` should always be less than or equal `SELECT budget FROM project WHERE id = ?;`

Is there any way to do this in Django, keeping in mind that multiple people may be accessing the web server and creating `Expense`s at the same time?

I am using postgresql as my database backend.

I have tried using `select_for_update` but that doesn't prevent `INSERT`s from taking place and it doesn't seem to work on aggregations anyway.

I was considering `save`ing the `Expense` to the database first, then query the total cost and remove the `Expense` if it's over-budget but then I would need that code to be outside of a transaction so that other threads can see it and then if the server stops mid-processing, the data could be left in an invalid state.

Comment: What did you try with `select_for_update`? Try selecting the `project` instead of the expenses.

Comment: @Alasdair That... was a lot simpler than I was expecting. I cannot believe I didn't think of that. Anyway, could you please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you add an answer with some example code, that would probably be more useful to other users in future than if I just copy my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Alasdair for pointing me in the right direction.

After filling out the fields of `inst` (a new `Expense`), do:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    project = models.Project.objects.select_for_update().get(
        pk=project_id)
    cost = project.total_cost()
    budget = project.budget

    if cost + inst.cost > budget:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('Over-budget'))

    self._inst.save()
```

Note that I have `total_cost` defined as a method on `Project`:

```
class Project:
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.expense_set.all().aggregate(
            t=Sum(F('cost')))['t']
```